# Assembly Concat two strings in local variable

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, masm32

im trying to make a small simple tcp chat in masm x86.
First i want to send the server the pc-name of the user. So i create a local variable with 80bytes and then call GetComputerName with ebp as destination pointer.

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

sub esp, 80
invoke GetComputerName, ebp, addr iUsernameLen
invoke send, sock, ebp, iUsernameLen, 0

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

This works really well, but then i tried adding a little prefix:

```
sub esp, 80
mov ebp, offset sNamePrefix
invoke GetComputerName, [ebp + (sizeof sNamePrefix)], addr iUsernameLen
invoke send, sock, ebp, iUsernameLen + (sizeof sNamePrefix), 0
```

This causes the program to crash and i have no real idea how to put a predefined string into a register (local variable).

Comment: Even your first version is wrong. Stack grows down, `ebp` points to the end of your allocated buffer, not the start. Anyway, to put your prefix you will need to copy it. Do you know C at least?

Comment: I don't get it, 1) I have no idea what the macro `invoke` does, show the full code. 2) I would guess it does use `ebp` as buffer for `GetComputerName`, but `ebp+0` points to the old `ebp` value and further to return address and stack of calling function, i.e. I would expect the buffer address (ebp-80) used. (and the smashing of stack should be obvious in debugger, if you would dare to actually debug your code and verify everything works as expected)

Comment: @Jester ok so if i try to substract 80 from ebp, only every second time the result contains the pcname

Comment: @Ped7g 1) ´invoke´ is just a macro for ´call´, which automatically pushes the parameters. 2) I tried substracting 80 from ebp, but than every second time calling, the result contains only weird chars.

Comment: You mean you put breakpoint before `call`, and checked which address is stored in stack as input buffer argument, and then after call it contains name only every second time? Then `GetComputerName` code has some bug. But I'm not sure what you are asking here, I'm not going to guess your code... [mcve]

Comment: If invoke works like you described, then I guess `push [ebp + (sizeof sNamePrefix)]` will not do what you think it should do. But anyway, rather put into question real code (either from listing file, or from disassembly), macros are very annoying.

Comment: If you `sub ebp, 80`, you'll break the stack when you try to return with `mov esp, ebp` / `pop ebp`.  After `sub esp, 80`, `esp` points to the start of the newly-allocated stack space.